# Text on top of each other pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have created a definition called message_display(text) but when ever i use it in my code the text gets on top of each other [in the lower left corner you see that hello and world is printed on top of eacht other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StJfd.jpg). Your help is appreciated

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
pygame.init()
win =  pygame.display.set_mode((800,700))
pygame.display.set_caption('Knights Of Dungeons')
gb = pygame.image.load('background.png')
font= pygame.font.SysFont('Gabriola', 30, False,True)
game = True
roll_dice = font.render('Press Enter To roll the dice' ,10,(0,0,0))
def dice():
    x = random.randint(1,6)
    return x




def message_display(text):
    dis_text = font.render(text, 10, (0,0,0))
    win.blit(dis_text,(10,650))
    pygame.display.update()




player_1 = font.render('Name: Kaan                 '+ 'Health:   100           
' + 'Damage:   0            ' + 'Armour: 0         ')

while game:

    pygame.time.delay(50)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           game = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:
      num_thrown = dice()
      roll_dice = font.render( 'The number you have throwen is: 
      '+str(0+num_thrown) ,20,(0,0,0))    
    win.blit(gb,(0,15))
    win.blit(player_1 ,(0,100))
    win.blit(roll_dice,(455,650))
    message_display('Hello')
    message_display('world')
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: you are placing 'hello' and 'world' in the same location. the message_display function never updates the location

Answer (score 0):

When I use pygame, I like to make my text display function much more general. Something like this:

```
import pygame as pg

def draw_text(surface, text, size, color, x, y):
    """Draw text to surface

       surface - Pygame surface to draw to
       text    - string text to draw
       size    - font size
       color   - color of text
       x       - x position of text on surface
       y       - y position of text on surface
    """
    font = pg.font.Font(font_name, size)
    text_surf = font.render(str(text), True, color)
    text_rect = text_surf.get_rect()
    text_rect.topleft = (x, y) # I use topleft here because that makes sense to me
                               # for English (unless you want it centered).
                               # But you can use any part of the rect to start drawing the text
    surface.blit(text_surf, text_rect)
```

Note that you also have to set up the `font_name`. You can do this inside or outside the function (if you just want one). I've done this globally for my usecase like this:

`font_name = pg.font.match_font('arial')`